# cume_dist for cumulative percent

Tags: sql, oracle

How can you do the examples on this page using the CUME_DIST analytical function?
http://www.webdotdev.com/nvd/content/view/82/99999999/1/16/

I'm using a proprietary database language and it has the CUME_DIST functions but can't seem to like the syntax of the examples on that page.

I'm especially interested in the last example. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but are you asking for help with the syntax of a proprietary language that no one here can know?

Comment: The syntax in the example is not usable in my language, but the proprietary language has a function called CUME_DIST.  So if it were possible to do the examples using CUME_DIST then I would be able to apply that knowledge in the proprietary language.

Comment: In other words how would you do these examples using CUME_DIST which is in Oracle and in my language. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Cumulative Distribution is a statistics function. It will generate an S-shaped curve for data that follows a normal distribution.

The last example on the page you cite generates a line if you place the cumulative sales on the independent axis and the Pct-To-total on the dependent axis.